# Getting id of just saved object In Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I have this code:

```
//defining partner
var Partner = sequelize.define('Partner', {
    order: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    image: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
    tableName: 'partners',
});
//creating partner instance
var partner=Partner.build();
partner.save().success(function(newpartner){
     console.log(newpartner.id);
});
```

When this code gets executed, 2 instances of partner are inserted to the database. The second one is pushed when I access `id` property of `partner`.

Here is the log from the console:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `partners` (`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES ('2014-08-16 13:13:26','2014-08-16 13:13:26');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `partners` (`id`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'2014-08-16 13:13:26','2014-08-16 13:13:26');
```

I need to get id of the partner and send it to client after persisting it to the database. How do I do it properly?
For now I just access `id` property without invoking `save()`, since it saves object anyway. However this is not documented. Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to work around it, but you should file a bug report or check to see if it's already been reported. What version are you using?

Comment: @furydevoid Yes, I was wondering if it's a bug. I'm using 1.7.9, the one that came with npm install.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to isolate the problem.

My mistake came from reading docs not thoroughly enough. Apparently setting associated object pushes entity to the Database (unlike in Doctrine, for example).
So my entity was saved during execution of the following code (not included in the question):

```
Partner.setManager(manager);
```

Where `Manager` is an entity in oneToMany relationship to Partner.
So the solution was to remove the save() call and use the `success` callback from the `setManager()`